# Routing problems with blazor, MVC and IIS

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, blazor

I am trying to get blazor working in an existing MVC application hosted in IIS. I followed the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241125/adding-server-side-blazor-to-an-existing-mvc-core-app)

There is also a similar example for razor pages. both work nicely in IIS express and self hosted, but when i try and use them in IIS they fail.

When hosted in IIS the framework is registered to the site and not the application. when opened in chrome the console gives the following errors:

blazor.server.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

I tried changing the framework script refrence from `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>` to `<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`. This solves the initial error, but  blazor falls over at the next step :

```
[2020-03-05T09:46:07.566Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'http://localhost/_blazor'.
_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-03-05T09:46:07.611Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Service Unavailable
e.log @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
s @ blazor.server.js:1
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
B @ blazor.server.js:1
e.getNegotiationResponse @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
B @ blazor.server.js:1
e.startInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
B @ blazor.server.js:1
e.start @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
v @ blazor.server.js:1
e.startInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
v @ blazor.server.js:1
e.startWithStateTransitions @ blazor.server.js:1
e.start @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
r @ blazor.server.js:8
S @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
r @ blazor.server.js:8
E @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
n @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
Show 22 more frames
blazor.server.js:1 [2020-03-05T09:46:07.612Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Service Unavailable
e.log @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
s @ blazor.server.js:1
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
B @ blazor.server.js:1
e.startInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
B @ blazor.server.js:1
e.start @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
v @ blazor.server.js:1
e.startInternal @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
v @ blazor.server.js:1
e.startWithStateTransitions @ blazor.server.js:1
e.start @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
r @ blazor.server.js:8
S @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
r @ blazor.server.js:8
E @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
n @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
Show 14 more frames
blazor.server.js:15 [2020-03-05T09:46:07.612Z] Error: Error: Service Unavailable
e.log @ blazor.server.js:15
C @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
s @ blazor.server.js:8
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
r @ blazor.server.js:8
S @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
r @ blazor.server.js:8
E @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
n @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
blazor.server.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
at e.send (blazor.server.js:1)
at e.sendMessage (blazor.server.js:1)
at e.sendWithProtocol (blazor.server.js:1)
at blazor.server.js:1
at new Promise ()
at e.invoke (blazor.server.js:1)
at e. (blazor.server.js:15)
at blazor.server.js:15
at Object.next (blazor.server.js:15)
at blazor.server.js:15
e.send @ blazor.server.js:1
e.sendMessage @ blazor.server.js:1
e.sendWithProtocol @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
e.invoke @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:15
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:15
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:15
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:15
r @ blazor.server.js:15
e.startCircuit @ blazor.server.js:15
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
a @ blazor.server.js:8
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:8
a @ blazor.server.js:8
Promise.then (async)
c @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
r @ blazor.server.js:8
E @ blazor.server.js:8
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:8
n @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.server.js:1
favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

The signalr hub seems to be pointing at the root site path in IIS instead of the application path.

Does anybody know how I can resolve this? To recreate the problem just download the source code [here](https://github.com/chrissainty/BlazorInExistingMVCApp) and setup a debug configuration pointing to IIS

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Check your `<base href` tag

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59833137/navigating-to-blazor-page-with-parameter-does-not-render-layout-or-anything/59836296#59836296

Comment: Thanks this is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from agua from mars the solution is to add the following tag to the head of _layout.cshtml

eg

```html
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="~/" />
```